# How do I fix my Asus Zenbook Pro 15 UX550GE's backlit keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, asus-laptop, backlight, zenbook

I have had this issue for months now, and I don't remember whether or not it happened after I got the laptop back from a screen repair or after some type of Windows 10 update. Basically, I've done just about every possible troubleshooting step. The keyboard's backlight used to work when I first got the laptop. I have uninstalled and reinstalled drivers, searched the system settings, played around in the device manager, and just recently completely wiped the hard drive and reinstalled Windows 10.

After the last step, the problem still persists. The hotkey that pertains to the backlight is F7. I press both F7 on its own as well as fn + F7 and nothing happens. All of the other hotkeys function properly, my only issue is with the F7 key. You would think that maybe the key itself isn't making contact on the motherboard, but I can enable caret browsing by using the key, so this isn't the issue. The prompt for the level of lighting doesn't appear at all, so it isn't a matter of the backlight being burnt out. Even in the Windows Mobility Center there is no option to adjust the backlight of the keyboard. Contacting Asus customer support didn't lead to any good results either.

I feel as though I've exhausted all options just short of sending the laptop in for repairs, which is extremely inconvenient since I need it daily. If anyone has any idea as to what I could do at this point, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard backlights are part of the keyboard (not external to the keyboard).

So you need to replace the keyboard. See if this is something you can do yourself, or whether you need to try a local repair shop.

I replaced the keyboard on my own ThinkPad X230 because the Power Switch had failed. I had to be explicit with the seller of the keyboard that it was a backlit keyboard and they supplied a keyboard with backlights. Works great.

Short sentence: Replace the keyboard with a factory replacement.